# Google New Play Services 7.8 Nearby Message via Ultrasonic or Inaudible example?

Tags: android, audio, google-play-services, data-transfer

As Title says,

Did anyone found sample for sending nearby Message via Ultrasonic Sound as mentioned in new Google Play Services 7.8:

"**Nearby uses a combination of Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and inaudible sound (using the device’s speaker and microphone) to establish proximity.**"

Anyone tried inaudible sound data transfer? I searched alot on this but couldn't find any.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can set the distance to short to use only ultrasonic mode, as it is mentioned in this [dev byte youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hultDpBS22s&feature=youtu.be&t=2m42s)

Comment: Thanks fot that video link... But I need sample code of just setting up the ultrasonic mode so that I can move on with some new apps by using ultrasound technology..